# vertical text alignment wont work within a div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to get the text in the div to be centered and in the middle but cant get it to move to the middle. I've tried putting it within a span but still to no avail.

```css
#head {
 Border-radius:6px;
 width:80%;
 height:50px;
 background-color:#F43434;
 color:white;
 margin: auto;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:50px;
 vertical-align:middle;
}

span {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">
 <span><b><i>Kilbride Classic Cuisine</i></b></span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Damiano I believe OP is talking about vertical align not horizontal.

Comment: `<span><b><i>Kilbride Classic Cuisine</i><b></span>` mis matched elements should be `<span><b><i>Kilbride Classic Cuisine</i></b></span>`

Comment: nope it isnt. im trying to get the text centered within the div block, nothing to do with screen sizes

Comment: @DarrenSweeney doesnt change it.

Comment: @chirag that doesnt work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what you want

**html**

```
<div id="head">
<span><b><i>Kilbride Classic Cuisine</i></b></span>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#head {
    Border-radius:6px;
    width:80%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#F43434;
    color:white;
    margin: auto;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:50px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

here is demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/2Lqt039x/1/

Comment: That works if i have the value of the table height in a pixel value but i have it as a percentage value in my code so surely it will become distorted if i change screen size?

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply `text-align: center;` and `vertical-align: middle;` to your text. Set `line-height` to the height of your `head div`.

```css
#head {
   Border-radius:6px;
   width:80%;
   height:50px;
   background-color:#F43434;
   color:white;
   margin: auto;
   margin-top:50px;
} 

p {
   text-align: center; 
   vertical-align: middle;
   line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">
    <p>
         <b><i>Kilbride Classic Cuisine</i></b>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is two lines with `flexbox`. `display:flex` on the parent and `margin:auto` on the child. The child will be centered both vertically and horizontally regardless of parent size.

[Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
#head {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top:50px;
    
    Border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid;
    background-color:#F43434;
    color:white;
    
    width:80%;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
    <div id = 'head' style ='display:flex'>
        <div style = 'margin:auto'>Kilbride ... </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different methods for vertically centring text and elements. In this case, you can achieve it, without the need for any extra markup, by using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes). The advantage of using this method rather than setting a `line-height` equal to the height if the `div` is that the text can break onto multiple lines and still be centred.

```css
#head {
  align-items:center;
  background-color:#f43434;
  border-radius:6px;
  color:#fff;
  display:flex;
  font-style:italic;
  font-weight:bold;
  height:50px;
  justify-content:center;
  margin:50px auto 0;
  text-align:center;
  width:80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">Kilbride Classic Cuisine</div>
```